# Application URL for enterprise deployment

Tags: xcode6

I just upgraded to XCode 6 because I needed to test an app on iOS 8. (The previous version couldn't connect to my iPad)

I've finished my fixes, and the app runs when I'm connected through USB. I'm preparing to roll this out through as an enterprise app.

There used to be an Application URL field when I'd build the app for enterprise distribution. This option appears to have been removed or moved. I've seen some other posts that say I can take a plist file from a previous version and update it for my new app. This seems a bit hokey to me.

Has that option moved, removed or was it deprecated? I've looked at Apple's documentation and forums, and haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score -1):

This option is not there in XCode 6.
You can use your .IPA file and any .PLIST file.
below thread works for me, answer given by MaxGabrial:
[xCode6 how to export an app with .plist for enterprise distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306876/xcode6-how-to-export-an-app-with-plist-for-enterprise-distribution/26307037#26307037)
Please let me know if you need any other help hosting app using url.