# xCode6 how to export an app with .plist for enterprise distribution?

Tags: ios, xcode6, ipa, enterprise-distribution

I'm trying to upload an app to a website that expects a .plist along with the app's ipa. 
The screenshot below is from the website.

I noticed that xCode6 has removed the checkbox to save for enterprise distribution from both the "ad hoc" and "enterprise" distribution option. I'm signing the app with a profile from a 299$/year enterprise program. Still I get no plist. **How can I distribute an app using xCode6 to get the enterprise plist option?**

Here's what I expect and saw in xCode5(there's no such checkbox in xCode6)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't using Xcode, but as a fallback you can just manually/programmatically edit the plist file. I do this because my continuous integration server distributes the builds, so I can't use Xcode's GUI to make the plist file.

Here's what an Enterprise distribution `.plist` looks like (copied from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/palaniraja/1051160)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1001/myawesomeapp.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.company.application</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>0.0.16</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>My Awesome App</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```